# Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space with $A\subseteq X$ Then, $x \in Cl(A)$ iff $N\cap A \neq \emptyset$ for all nbhd's of X

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space with $A\subseteq X$ Then, $x \in Cl(A)$ iff $N\cap A \neq \emptyset$ for all nbhd's of X

($\Rightarrow$) Assume $x\in Cl(A)$

By definition there's a closed set U such that $Cl(A)=\cap \{U\subseteq X : U \text{is a closed set and} A \subseteq U \}$

$\Rightarrow A \subseteq Cl(A)$

$\Rightarrow x \in A \subseteq Cl(A)$

$\Rightarrow N \cap A \neq \emptyset$ $\forall$ neighborhoods of X

Am I missing something with the first part of this proof?

Comment: Two things that are definitely missing: your definition of closure and your definition of closed set. There are multiple equivalent ones, including the theorem you're trying to prove, and different texts do it differently. We need to know where you're starting.

Answer (score 1):

The implication $A\subseteq Cl(A) \implies x\in A\subseteq Cl(A)$ is invalid, as it may be possible that $x\in Cl(A)\setminus A$.

(If you draw an image, you get $Cl(A)$ when you add the *boundary* of $A$.)

The point is, that the points on boundary still have the given property: 
Let $N$ be an open neighborhood of a point $x\in Cl(A)$. Then its complement $X\setminus N$ is closed, and $x\notin X\setminus N$. 
If $N$ was disjoint to $A$, that would mean $A\subseteq X\setminus N\ $ so $Cl(A)\subseteq X\setminus N$. But that implies $x\in X\setminus N$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

So your definition is that the closure of $A \subset X$ is the intersection of all closed sets that contain $A$ as a subset (and this is the intersection of at least the set $X$).

Let $A \subset X$, and let $\overline{A}$ be the closure of $A$ in this definition.
Let $x \in \overline{A}$, and let $N$ be any neighbourhood of $x$, so we have an open set $O$ of $X$ such that $x \in O \subset N$ (your definition of neighbourhood might state that $N = O$, but we don't need it). Now **if** $A \cap O = \emptyset$, this just says that $A \subset X \setminus O$, and the latter set is closed, and so it is one of the sets in the intersection that defined $\overline{A}$ to begin with. So then $\overline{A} \subset X \setminus O$, but $x$ itself contradicts this, as it is in the left hand side but not in the right hand side. This must mean that $A \cap O \neq \emptyset$ and so also $A \cap N \neq \emptyset$, as is required.

Now let $x$ be such that every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$. Let $C$ be any closed set that contains $A$ as a subset. Then **if** $x \notin C$, $X \setminus C$ would be an open neighbourhood of $x$ that missed $A$, contrary to assumption. So $x \in C$ so by the definition of $\overline{A}$, $x \in \overline{A}$ and we have equality.